# VueJS transition-group is not working on images, how can I fade images?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-transition-group

I'm trying to create an image slider, which fades the images. Image 1 should fade-out at the same moment as image 2 fades in. In other words: there shouldn't be a gap between them. Right now it does nothing like fading. The code is working, as so far that when the user clicks "next", the current images disappears, 0.9s later the next image appears. There is a delay of 0.9s between them (the same amount as declared in the CSS), so somehow it recognizes the transition time. It is only not fading, after clicking the button it immediately disappears. What am I missing?

My code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition-group name='fade' tag='div'>
      <div v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key='i'>
        <img :src="currentImg" />
      </div>
    </transition-group>
    <a class="prev" @click="prev" href='#'>&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" @click="next" href='#'>&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/12/15/24/amsterdam-1089646_1280.jpg',
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/17/23/03/usa-1206240_1280.jpg',
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/15/14/27/eiffel-tower-768501_1280.jpg',
        'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/04/19/30/berlin-cathedral-1882397_1280.jpg'
        ],
      timer: null,
      currentIndex: 0,
      show: true
    };
  },

  mounted: function () {
    this.startSlide();
  },

  methods: {
    startSlide: function () {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 4000);
    },

    next: function () {
      this.currentIndex += 1;
    },
    prev: function () {
      this.currentIndex -= 1;
    },
  },

  computed: {
    currentImg: function () {
      return this.images[Math.abs(this.currentIndex) % this.images.length];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
height:600px;
width:100%
  }

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

</style>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the visibility attribute from your css classes while leaving opacity. Visibility is true or false but nothing inbetween so can‘t be transitioned.

Comment: The same, it disappears and after 0.9s the next images appears, at once (no fading)

Comment: It appears that the fading is working, but somehow the images is replaced somewhere else off canvas as soon as the transition starts. When transition ends, the image returns on its original position

Answer (score 0):

Change `.fade-enter` to `.fade-enter-from`.

[See example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: tried that already, unfortunately same effect (better said: no effect)

Comment: Have you seen the example in the link? It works.

Comment: Somehow, when I copy my code in the link, it also works. But in my browser it is not...

Answer (score 0):

The `position:absolute` was messing things up here... Removed this line, now it works like a charm!